# How can I include saving in a text file in executable file?

Tags: c#, executable

I have an application in Visual Studio C# which includes saving into a text file, how can I have a .exe sent to another computer and not have an exception in saving?

I need to send a .exe file by email (Yes it's possible) and this application includes saving the state of the game. How can I send this .exe file and let the user be able to save in his computer please?

The problem is that when I send my application's executable file on another computer, I'm getting an exception in saving. Because on the other computer I don't have the text file which I'm saving the game.

I am saving here :

StreamWriter myFile = File.CreateText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"//ConnectFour.txt");

in the obj/Debug/ of the project..

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Saving to a text file is well documented. What specifically do you have a problem with? Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: And please post exact exception message you are getting. You are not tracing/showing exceptions - start with that.

Comment: I don't know what's the exception.. I'm just catching the general Exception class.. and displaying a message box with "Cannot save to file" message only therefore since I don't have the code on the other computer I don't know what exception is being caught :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely current location is not writable by current user.

Using "current directory" is dangerous as you have no control over where application is launched from. It is very useful for command line utilities, but not so much for regular windowed applications. Use location that you know you can save files to - i.e. "My Documents".

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\",
   ConnectFour.txt");
using(var  myFile = File.CreateText(filePAth))
{
  // save data here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei, it worked like you said! I can save on the other computer now thanks to you :D

Comment: After I checked on multiple computers, this worked on some, and didn't work on others :/ I'm thinking it's because of the .NET Framework the other computers has installed. However I wish I know how to solve this

Answer (score 2):

Sending an executable should work just fine.

Make sure the other computer has the appropriate Microsoft .NET Framework installed.

Latest framework installer: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx)

Also, make sure the path inwhich you're saving the file to exists on the remote computer.  For example, if you're trying to save to the D:\ drive and it doesn't exist.  You will get an exception.

Comment: I'm saving the file in the obj/Debug directory in my project.. and I'm only sending the .exe file.. So that's wrong aye? Cause the directory I have for the project, doesn't exist in the other computer :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem when sending executables by email are the anti-virus-scanners. Some of them refuse e-mails containing executables. Others accept the mails but delete the attachment.

The solution consists in hiding the executable. This can be done by zipping the executable and sending the zip-file.

Often this is enough to solve the problem but some anti-virus-scanners are very smart and even recognize executables within the zip-attachment. The solution here is to encrypt the zip-file with a password. I often just use the password "pwd" and mention it in the e-mail text. The anti-viruses are not (yet) smart enough to understand this text.

---

**UPDATE**

Now I understand your problem. It has nothing to do with sending the executable.

An application can determine from which directory it has been started like this

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath
);
```

An alternative is (if you don't have a reference to WinForms):

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
);
```

Comment: The problem isn't to send the .exe file.. I managed to send it and it was received by the other end. The problem is that I don't know if I am saving the text file in the right directory to be accessible for other computers

Comment: I don't understand how you can save the file when sending it by e-mail.

Comment: I am creating a file like this:

StreamWriter myFile = File.CreateText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"//ConnectFour.txt");

Do you think it will be created in the current directory of the running application on the other computer? or do I have to use something else?

Comment: I added a solution that gets the directory of the executable. Note that `GetCurrentDirectory` can be any directory that has been accessed recently. It is not necessarily the one from which your app has been started.

Comment: I found this too: var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\ConnectFour.txt");  .. and it's working fine on one friend's computer however not on another.. Do you think that this is affected by the .NET Framework the receiver has installed? If yes, have you any idea how I can make my program unreliable to the .NET Framework?

Comment: I think that the problem is more related to the specific Windows installation and is probably not a .NET specific problem. what you could do is to place a configuration file in the same folder where the application is installed that contains a path to a location specified by the user. Another option is to use the folder `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not have sufficient privileges to save the file on the remote machine. If you give us more information on the exact exception that is being thrown (type of exception, message, stack trace, etc) you will get a more accurate answer.